# My Exception is not working

Tags: java

I am creating 3 things right now; a driver, a class and an exception.

Currently having trouble with my book store class recognizing the exceptions on my book class.

What am I doing wrong?

Driver: edited by the given suggestion by @Satoshi Kouno

```js
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class BookStore{
 
    
        
   public static void main(String arg[ ]) throws Exception{
   
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int isbn=0;
      int quantity = 0;
      String title = "";
      Book oneBook;
      boolean exit = false;
      List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>(); //here  
    
     while(true){
    try{
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter title: ");
    title = sc.nextLine( );
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter isbn: ");
    isbn = sc.nextInt( );
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
    quantity = sc.nextInt( );
    System.out.println();   

 // Validation Codes
 // Condition
    if(isbn !=0 && quantity != 0 && !"".equals(title))
    {
    oneBook = new Book(title, isbn, quantity);
    bookList.add(oneBook); //create a list in main
    System.out.println("Book added in the list."); 
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Book not added");
         break;
       }
    }
     
     catch(InputMismatchException ime){
        System.out.println("you did not enter a number");  
     }
     catch (BookException be){
        System.out.println(be.getMessage( ));  // 
}
}
  for(int i = bookList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.println(bookList.get(i));
    }   
    }  //main method
}   //class
```

Class:

```
public class Book{
//instance variables
private String title = "";
private int isbn;
private int quantity;

public Book (String title, int isbn, int quantity)throws Exception{     
//constructors

     setTitle(title);
     setIsbn(isbn);
     setQuantity(quantity);

   }
public String toString( ){ //toString Method

    String s = "";
    s = s + "Title: " + this.title + "\nISBN: " + this.isbn +   "\nQuantity: " + this.quantity + "\n";
    return s;

    }

public String getTitle( ){
    return this.title;
    }
public int getisbn( ){
    return this.isbn;
    }
public int getquantity( ){  
    return this.quantity;
    }

//mutator methods
public void setTitle(String newtitle )throws BookException{
    if(newtitle.length()<1){
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("Title cannot be blank");
    throw be;
    }
    else{
    this.title=newtitle;
    }
}

public void setIsbn(int newisbn)throws BookException{
    if (isbn <= 1000 || isbn >= 10000) {
    this.isbn = newisbn;
    }
    else{
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("ISBN should be between 1000 and 10000.");
    throw be;
    }
}

public void setQuantity(int newquantity)throws BookException{
   if(newquantity>=0){
   this.quantity = newquantity;
    }
   else{
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("Quantity can't be a negative number.");
    throw be;
     }
  }

}
```

And my exception class: edited #2

```
public class BookException extends Exception {
//instance variable
private String message = "";

public BookException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public void setMessage(String newMessage) {
    this.message = newMessage;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
}
```

}
Trying to get my class to work with my driver but it's not working.

**EDIT!! PSA**
i forgot to point out the requirements of my driver class

- Read the book title from the user
- Read the book ISBN from the user
- Read the book in stock quantity from the user
- Your program should continue to read the book information from the user until all the entries from the user for all the fields are blank or zero.
- Your program will store valid book objects into an ArrayList (only valid objects)
- Your program will then print the list all the "valid" Books entered by the user in the reverse order in which the books were entered.
- As the user is entering information, the program should give feedback such as reporting that an item has been added to the ArrayList, or reporting any errors found.

my book and exception class are not needed changes already

they just want me to make my own driver to run with both of them and their exceptions

Comment: What do you mean "recognizing the exceptions"?

Comment: You shouldn't have a setter for the message: pass in the message as a constructor parameter, so that you'd write `throw new BookException("Quantity...")`; you'd invoke `super(message)` in your constructor which now takes a String parameter.

Comment: You throw that exception from the setTitle method, but I don't see any calls to it.  Did I miss it?

Comment: first of all you need to "throw BookException();" then and then you are able to catch into BookException block.

Comment: Define "it's not working". Precisely. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Also, please indent your code.

Comment: @vishalgajera there is no requirement to throw an exception immediately upon instantiation.

Comment: in the book class there are countless bookexceptions inside, i am trying to make my bookstore class to pop up those exceptions but it's not doing any "(

Comment: "countless" - none of them are needed or well done.  An IllegalArgumentException would be better.  Where do you call any of those methods?  When is one of those "countless" exceptions thrown?

Comment: in my mutator methods in the book class

Answer (score 3):

Your class is not working to due this:

```
// Validation Codes
// Condition
if(isbn !=0 && quantity != 0 && title != null && title != "")
```

```
title != ""
```

This condition will be never and never verified so will not enter in the part of code where you create the `Book` object:

To compare String values just replace it by:

```
!"".equals(title);
```

**@See** [String#equals() JavaDOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

or use apache lang classes (probably you will have to import it):

```
StringUtils.isNotEmpty(title);
```

**Moreover:**

I suggest you to modify your custom exception class adding the construct:

```
public class BookException extends Exception {

    public BookException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

And in `Book#setTitle` and the other one setters raise it by:

```
throw new BookException("Title cannot be blank!");
```

Hope this help.

**Update:**

Analysing the code i checked others things like:

```
if (isbn <= 1000 || isbn >= 10000) {
    this.isbn = newisbn;
} else {
    BookException be = new BookException( );
    be.setMessage("ISBN should be between 1000 and 10000.");
    throw be;
}
```

This check is wrong for me, probably you wanted to do this:

```
isbn >= 1000 && isbn <= 10000
```

Comment: kinda confuse on the first part on how i should put the codes , how should i replace that then? editing the code or showing me an edited one would be helpful ;_; ,,,

Comment: i just want "Title cannot be blank", ISBN should be between 1000 and 10000 and Quantity can't be a negative number. from my book class ;_; but i don't know what i need to do much,., not really good at this so i apologize

Comment: i even did this catch (BookException be){
        System.out.println(be.getMessage( ));   in my bookstore driver but nope

Comment: how would you like me to change this then if(isbn !=0 && quantity != 0 && title != null && title != "") ?

Comment: by this: `if(isbn !=0 && quantity != 0 && !"".equals(title))`

Comment: nice i manage to fix it but it is showing errors on my book class

Comment: error: constructor BookException in class BookException cannot be applied to given types;
    BookException be = new BookException( );
                       ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: this is showing on all three mutators in my book class

Comment: for sure: you cannot construct the exception since your constructor provide a string as argument. You will have to pass the error message you want to throw. For example: `BookException be = new BookException( "now it's happening this error!");`

Comment: ISBN 10 or 13?  Funny, I think those should be strings in real life. Integers won't work.

Comment: did your stuff satoshi but it's not giving me the exceptions that i gave out on my book class,, my driver is not showing the exceptions if i do them